# How to convert an array to a different format?

Tags: php

Hi 
i want to convert this array where id as key and  name value pair

```
Array(
    [4882] => treatment
    [4876] => Advance
    [4854] => Applied Clinical
)
```

to

```
Array(
    [0] => Array([id] => 4882, [name] => treatment)
    [1] => Array([id] => 4876, [name] => Advance)
    [2] => Array([id] => 4854, [name] => Applied Clinical)
)
```

Comment: You have to give a more complete example. It is not clear how the entries should be mapped.

Comment: I see no correlation between both arrays beyond `$array2 = array(array('id' => 5391, 'name' => $array1[4876]))`.

Comment: are the closers reading the answers given  ?

Comment: @mcgrailm Yes, that doesn't improve the question though.

Comment: @deceze that is true but maybe the OP hasn't gotten to it yet, and if its understandable enough to receive 3 very similar answers how is it not a real question ?

Comment: There you go, fixed up the question to match the given answers, *assuming* that's what @srikanth actually meant.

Comment: @srikanth saladi from the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)  When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($original_array as $key=>$value){
    $new_arrays[] = array('id'=>$key,'name'=>$value);
}

print_r($new_arrays);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so:

```
$output_arr = array();
foreach($input_arr as $key => $value)
  $output_arr[] = array('id' => $key, 'name' => $value);
```

And then you can use $output_arr as converted array or assign its contents to $input_arr:

```
$input_arr = &$output_arr;
```

Answer (score 2):

`$input` is your first array, `$output` will hold the resulting array

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $id => $name)
{
  $output[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name);
}
```